# How to combine a function, for outputting a star pattern, with an input loop

Tags: python

I have a working function to convert letters to 5x5 star patterns:

```
def pattern():
    for i in range(len(name)):
        if name [i] =="B":
            print_B = [[" " for i in range (5)] for j in range (5)]
            for row in range(5):
                for col in range(5):
                    if (col==0) or (col==4 and (row!=0 and row!=2 and row!=4)) or ((row==0 or row==2 or row==4) and (col>0 and col<4)):
                        print_B[row] [col] = "*"
            list2.append(print_B)
                    
        elif name [i] =="A":
            print_A = [[" " for i in range (5)] for j in range (5)]
            for row in range(5):
                for col in range(5):
                    if (row==0 and 1<col<3)or((row==1 and 0<col<2)or(row==1 and 2<col<4))or(row==2 and 0<=col)or((row==3 or row==4) and (0<=col<1 or 3<col>=4)):
                        print_A[row] [col] = "*"
            list2.append(print_A)
        
        elif name [i] =="L":
            print_L = [[" " for i in range (5)] for j in range (5)]
            for row in range(5):
                for col in range(5):
                    if ((col==0) and row<=4) or ((row==4) and (0<col<=4)):
                        print_L[row] [col] = "*"
            list2.append(print_L)
        else:
            print("INVALID")
            
    return list2

name = input("Enter the name:")
list2 = []
list3 = pattern()

for i in range (5):
    for j in range(len(list3)):
        for k in range(5):
            print(list3[j][i][k],end=" ")
        print(end=" ")
    print ()
```

I want to use this function in my loop where the user inputs a word, and the corresponding pattern is printed. The loop stops when the user types ‘stop’.

Eventually, I want to add the entire alphabet to this code, but I can't figure out how to make the below loop and input code to work with the above code.

```
def information_gathering_phase():
    while True:  
        word = input("Enter a word from the letters 'B', 'A' and/or 'L' (or type 'stop' to stop the program): ") 
        if word == 'stop' or word == 'STOP': 
            return None 
        elif not all(letter in 'BAL' for letter in word): 
            print("Invalid word! Please try again...") 
        else:
            return word
```

and...

```
def main():
    while True:
        word = information_gathering_phase()
        if word is None: 
            print("Thanks for trying my program...Bye for now!")
            break 
        else:
            ??? I don't know - ? some return statement

if __name__ == '__main__': 
    main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, `pattern` should take the input word as argument, and should declare `list2` as a local name:

```
def pattern(name):  # Parameter
    list2 = []   # Moved here as a local name
```

Then, in the `else` block of your `main`, call `pattern` like this:

```
        else:
            list3 = pattern(word)
            
            for i in range (5):
                for j in range(len(list3)):
                    for k in range(5):
                        print(list3[j][i][k],end=" ")
                    print(end=" ")
                print ()
```

This similar code should be removed from your first code snippet.

So in total:

```
def pattern(name):  # Parameter
    list2 = []   # Moved here as a local name
    for i in range(len(name)):
        if name [i] =="B":
            print_B = [[" " for i in range (5)] for j in range (5)]
            for row in range(5):
                for col in range(5):
                    if (col==0) or (col==4 and (row!=0 and row!=2 and row!=4)) or ((row==0 or row==2 or row==4) and (col>0 and col<4)):
                        print_B[row] [col] = "*"
            list2.append(print_B)

        elif name [i] =="A":
            print_A = [[" " for i in range (5)] for j in range (5)]
            for row in range(5):
                for col in range(5):
                    if (row==0 and 1<col<3)or((row==1 and 0<col<2)or(row==1 and 2<col<4))or(row==2 and 0<=col)or((row==3 or row==4) and (0<=col<1 or 3<col>=4)):
                        print_A[row] [col] = "*"
            list2.append(print_A)

        elif name [i] =="L":
            print_L = [[" " for i in range (5)] for j in range (5)]
            for row in range(5):
                for col in range(5):
                    if ((col==0) and row<=4) or ((row==4) and (0<col<=4)):
                        print_L[row] [col] = "*"
            list2.append(print_L)
        else:
            print("INVALID")

    return list2


def information_gathering_phase():
    while True:  
        word = input("Enter a word from the letters 'B', 'A' and/or 'L' (or type 'stop' to stop the program): ") 
        if word == 'stop' or word == 'STOP': 
            return None 
        elif not all(letter in 'BAL' for letter in word): 
            print("Invalid word! Please try again...") 
        else:
            return word


def main():
    while True:
        word = information_gathering_phase()
        if word is None: 
            print("Thanks for trying my program...Bye for now!")
            break 
        else:
            list3 = pattern(word)
            
            for i in range (5):
                for j in range(len(list3)):
                    for k in range(5):
                        print(list3[j][i][k],end=" ")
                    print(end=" ")
                print ()
            
if __name__ == '__main__': 
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

As your goal is to generate patterns for the whole alphabet, it is better if you don't generate those patterns through program logic, but make it more *data-driven*. Provide the patterns for each letter as a star-string, and then look up each string based on the word you get.

Here is how that could look:

```
patterns = """
  *  ****  *** **** ********** *** *   * ***   ****  * *    *   **   * *** ****  *** ****  **********   **   **   **   **   ******
 * * *   **   **   **    *    *    *   *  *      ** *  *    ** ****  **   **   **   **   **      *  *   **   **   * * *  * *    * 
********* *    *   ****  ***  *  *******  *      ***   *    * * ** * **   ***** * * *****  ***   *  *   * * * * * *  *    *    *  
*   **   **   **   **    *    *   **   *  *  *   ** *  *    *   **  ***   **    *  * *  *     *  *  *   * * * ** ** * *  *    *   
*   *****  *** **** ******     *** *   * ***  *** *  * ******   **   * *** *     ** **   *****   *   ***   *  *   **   **    *****
""".strip("\n").splitlines()

def pattern(word):  
    width = len(patterns[0]) // 26
    offsets = [(ord(letter) - ord("A")) * width for letter in word]
    return "\n".join(
        " ".join(line[offset:offset+width] for offset in offsets)
        for line in patterns
    )


def information_gathering_phase():
    while True:  
        word = input("Enter a word with English capital letters only (or enter nothing to exit): ") 
        if all("A" <= letter <= "Z" for letter in word): 
            return word
        print("Invalid word! Please try again...") 
        

def main():
    while True:
        word = information_gathering_phase()
        if not word: 
            print("Thanks for trying my program...Bye for now!")
            break 
        print(pattern(word))

if __name__ == '__main__': 
    main()
```

### Explanation

`width` will get the width of an individual letter pattern. As there are 26 letters encoded in `patterns`, the first line has a length that is 26 times that width. So by dividing that string length by 26 we get the width of a single letter pattern (which is 5).

The expression `ord(letter) - ord("A")` gives us the index in the alphabet of `letter`. If `letter` is "A", this evaluates to 0, when "B" to 1, ...etc. By multiplying that with `width` we get the index (offset) of the first character in `patterns[row]` (for any `row`) that relates to the pattern we need for `letter`. And `offsets` gathers all these starting indices for the letters in the input word.

The slice `offset:offset+width` gets all characters on the same `line` that belong to the letter pattern we need. We get these slices for each offset, and join them with a space (to separate the patterns for the different letters).

This is repeated for each line in the pattern (using the same offsets), so that we get 5 lines of output, which are joined by a line break.

Comment: I love the above code of the 2nd answer that works perfect although I'll stick to the first answer for now as I know what it is doing and where. I'm very curious however... How does the program match the letters I type. Is it something to do with "//26" or something I just can't see? This is a very interesting code!

Comment: I added a little explanation at the end of this answer.

Comment: Thanks for that - that's one of the most magical codes I've seen so far. I didn't realise Python could work from patterns to figure out what I type. Pretty cool!

Comment: Yes, but that is not specific for Python. One can do something similar in any (general purpose) program language (like C, C++, C#, Java, PHP, TypeScript, ...)